# PagedCollectionView custom sorting

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

Is it possible to customize sorting in PagedCollectionView in Silverlight4?
It seems to me that I have possiblility to sort this collections by given property. I can also set if I want to sort collection ascending or descending. However I can't see a possibility to set a custom sorting - using some kind of comparer or something like that.

Simplest sorting could be implemented this way

```
PlayerPagedCollection = new PagedCollectionView();
PlayerPagedCollection.SortDescriptions.Clear();
PlayerPagedCollection.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Name",ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Is it possible to somehow set a custom sorting ?? I need to make it work on Silverlight4

Answer (score 0):

The extra complexity isn't ideal, but this works for me.

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    private YourDomainContext context;
    private IOrderedEnumerable<Person> people;
    private PagedCollectionView view;
    private PersonComparer personComparer;

    public YourViewModel()
    {
        context = new YourDomainContext();
        personComparer = new PersonComparer()
        {
            Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending
        };
        people = context.People.OrderBy(p => p, personComparer);
        view = new PagedCollectionView(people);
    }

    public void Sort()
    {
        using (view.DeferRefresh())
        {
            personComparer.Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;

            //this triggers the IOrderedEnumerable to resort
            FlightTurnaroundProcessesView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        }
    }
}

public class PersonComparer : IComparer<Person>
{
    public ListSortDirection Direction { get; set; }

    public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        //add any custom sorting here
        return x.CompareTo(y) * GetDirection();
    }

    private int GetDirection()
    {
        return Direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```